# Connect ESP32 to phone without application over bluetooth classic

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, android-bluetooth, arduino-esp32

I am using ESP32 dev module with Arduino IDE.
ESP version : 2.0.5
Arduino version : 2.0.2

My goal is to get the MAC address of the devices(phones to be specific). I can get that easily if I can connect to EPS32 but I could find a way to do this without using application. I can not use or create application as this will be used for a number of people and devices. Is it possible to do this ?

If not, than is it possible to do the same using paring functionality ? I do get a callback in ESP32 when new device tries to pair however it will stay paired in the device. Can I remove my EPS32 from "paired devices" from phone automatically (from ESP32) ? Because if I will not do that than I will not get the callback next time as it work only when we pair first time.

In other word I want to get the MAC address of the device using options from phone's settings.

I am using SerialBluetooth library. In my phone after pairing I get option for connect.

[image]

If I press it for EPS32 than it gives no response in phone and in ESP32 as well. I have verbose turned on in EP32 that prints every callback. Do I have to change something to connect device from this method ?
I am new to this topic so I do not know the working of Bluetooth in detail. Hope someone can guide me here.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do. If we talk about classic Bluetooth then to get Bluetooth MAC address of server device (let say server is your phone, client is ESP32) all you need to do is to run Bluetooth discovering (HCI Inquery) on ESP32 side. This operation returns MAC addresses of all Bluetooth devices that are in discoverable mode. In case of BLE server (peripheral) must advertise to be discovered and client (central) must monitor BLE advertisements. In any case all modern phones needs to be switched to discovrable mode by: classic - BT settings opened, LE - some BLE adv is app running.